# ECHO program in C#

Tags: c#, .net

i'm trying to make a program in C# that behaves like the well-known echo command. Everything works fine except when I try to print a quoted String.

For example, in the echo command you type:

```
echo "Hello, world!"
```

And you get as output:

```
"Hello, world"
```

But when I run my program I get:

```
Hello, world!
```

This is the code:

```
using System;

namespace CSharpEcho
{
    public class Echo
    {
        public static void Main(String[] argv)
        {
            Int32 ArgsLength = argv.Length;

            if(ArgsLength == 0)
                Console.WriteLine("You have to write something!");
            else
            {
                String Str = "";

                foreach(String args in argv)
                {
                    Str += args + " ";
                }

                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}", Str));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use String.Join(" ", argv) instead?

Comment: Also using a String.Format("{0}", Str)) is pretty useless ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Environment.CommandLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.commandline.aspx) holds exact command line contents.

So your code can be :

```
public static void Main(String[] argv)
{
  Console.WriteLine(Environment.CommandLine);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Double-quote characters in strings are kind of tricky. Try this:

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Format(@"""{0}""", Str));
```

The @ symbol makes the string into a string literal, meaning that there are no "escape" characters. The outer pair of double-quotes are the normal quotes around a string, and the inner double-pair of double quotes are actual quote characters.

Comment: The `Str` string is built up from the arguments - the Console.WriteLine call would merely print quotes around the concatenated arguments.

Comment: Yes.. the problem is that quotes are stripped from argv. Your solution would mean that `program.exe "hello"` and `program.exe hello` will both print `"hello"`. OP wants quotes only if quotes were typed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your output to be "Hello, world". You can use something like this:

```
var text = "\"Hello, World\"";
```